# Getting error when trying to build a docker file - failed to create LLB definition

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker file and I am getting this error

```
------
      => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/bitnami/minideb:stretch                                            2.5s
 => [auth] bitnami/minideb:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                      0.0s
  [internal] load metadata for docker.io/bitnami/minideb:stretch:


    failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch oauth token: Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Abitnami%2Fminideb%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`
```

I just downloaded this file from git repo and tried to build it, but I am getting this above mentioned error.
I have tried so far:

- `docker login` and `docker pull hello-world/docker pull docker.io/bitnami/minideb:stretch` works for me.
- Tried restarting docker desktop, I am on a mac
- Tried resetting to factory settings, and then restarting docker desktop, still no luck.

This is how I am building it:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile .
```

This is what is there in the docker file

```
FROM bitnami/minideb:stretch
RUN apt-get  –no-install-recommends update
&& apt-get –no-install-recommends install -y openssh-client openssl libexpat1 
 && sh /tmp/nso --system-install --non-interactive
```

the docker file is a really big one, so I cannot post the entire file here.

Comment: Did you try `docker pull debian:buster`?

Comment: okay, my bad, this docker pull does not work. wrong base image. But I have different image as well, where I have the same error. the base image is FROM bitnami/minideb:stretch, docker pull works for this one, but not in the docker file.

Comment: Can you please update your post with the Dockerfile updated?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistakes in your `Dockerfile` formatting.

- You need to have a backslash at the end of each line before starting a new line with commands.

Please check the `Dockerfile` below:

```
FROM bitnami/minideb:stretch

RUN apt-get --no-install-recommends update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y openssh-client \
    openssl libexpat1 \
```

**Note:** I removed the last line of your `Dockerfile` because I don't understand what you want to do with it.

Comment: I copy pasted this exact file, I have the same error..docker build -f Dockerfile.pp .

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the Dockerfile and the error?